# Access structure variable inside a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char member1[100];
    char member2[100];
} struct1_t;

typedef struct
{
    struct1_t member_struct1;
} struct2_t;

typedef struct1_t *struct1_ptr;
typedef struct2_t *struct2_ptr;
```

I want to access `member_struct1` inside `struct2` but I get non-scalar conversion error in the following code:

```
struct2_ptr driver = (struct2_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct2_t));
driver->member_struct1 = (struct1_t)malloc(sizeof(struct1_t));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the purpose of the second `malloc`??? What are you trying to allocate by it and why?

Comment: I need to assign a new value to memner_struct1 of struct2

Comment: There no need for the second `malloc` in order to "assign a new value to memner struct1 of struct2". The first `malloc` allocated the memory, now you can just assign everything you want to assign inside that memory. There's no need for any additional `malloc`s. Why did you put that second `malloc` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call

```
struct2_ptr driver = (struct2_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct2_t));
```

allocates storage for `member_struct1` so you can safely dereference `driver->member_struct1` after the first `malloc` and remove your second line.

Comment: I tried this in place of the second line: strcpy(((struct1_t)driver)->member_struct1->member1, "sample string"); but this throws "conversion to non-scalar type requested"

Comment: Try `strcpy(driver->member_struct1.member1, "sample string");`.  The cast was wrong and members of `member_struct1` are by value rather than pointer so are accessed using the structure dereference operator `.`

Answer (score 2):

You're casting a pointer to a struct type:

```
driver->member_struct1 = (struct1_t)malloc(sizeof(struct1_t));
```

`malloc` returns a pointer. `struct1_t` is not a pointer type. Make `member_struct1` a pointer type. And don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

E.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char member1[100];
    char member2[100];
} struct1_t;
typedef struct1_t *struct1_ptr;

typedef struct
{
    struct1_ptr member_struct1;
} struct2_t;
typedef struct2_t *struct2_ptr;

void your_func()
{
    struct2_ptr driver = malloc(sizeof(struct2_t));
    driver->member_struct1 = malloc(sizeof(struct1_t));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why is the second `malloc` required?  `member_struct1` isn't a pointer so will have had space allocated by the allocation of `driver`

Comment: @simonc: It's not required. I just assumed that he wanted to allocate dynamically, since you know, he was using `malloc`. :P